# window.print is not printing text of input element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I know this question was asked before. But I could not found a sure solution for it yet. Though I tried all the previous solutions, it doesn't work.

I am doing some coding on AngularJS and I have to print the form data once it is filled. However when I print it, all the form fields are showing empty in the printout. Somewhere it is suggested to handle the issue using CSS with the media query below. But still no success. So what could be the possible solution?

#### Media query:

```
"@media print { 
@page { margin: 0; }
body {display:none}     
}"
```

#### JS:

```
    $scope.printDiv = function(divName) {

    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;

    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
    popupWin.document.close();      
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div>
<div id='printable'>
<p class="address">ADDRESS:<br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="Address_line1" maxlength="40" placeholder="Address line 1" style="border:1px solid white" width="60"/> <br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="Address_line2" maxlength="30" placeholder="Address line 2" style="border:1px solid white" /> <br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="Address_line3" maxlength="30" placeholder="Address line 3" style="border:1px solid white" /> <br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="Address_line4" maxlength="30" placeholder="Address line 4" style="border:1px solid white" />
<br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="Address_line5" maxlength="30" placeholder="Address line 5" style="border:1px solid white" />
<br/>

</p>
</div>
<button style="margin:auto;display:block;" ng-click="printDiv('printable');">Print</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the values are entered into the inputs, those are not stored in the HTML markup. Thus the *.innerHTML* property of the element being referenced won't contain those values.

One solution is to use [ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) for each input with the same model name as the controller property bound to *ng-model*.

```
<input ng-value="Address_line1" type="text" ng-model="Address_line1" maxlength="40" placeholder="Address line 1" style="border:1px solid white" width="60"/><br />
<input ng-value="Address_line2" type="text" ng-model="Address_line2" maxlength="30" placeholder="Address line 2" style="border:1px solid white" /> <br/>
<input ng-value="Address_line3" type="text" ng-model="Address_line3" maxlength="30" placeholder="Address line 3" style="border:1px solid white" /> <br/>
<input ng-value="Address_line4" type="text" ng-model="Address_line4" maxlength="30" placeholder="Address line 4" style="border:1px solid white" /> <br/>
<input ng-value="Address_line5" type="text" ng-model="Address_line5" maxlength="30" placeholder="Address line 5" style="border:1px solid white" />
```

That will simulate *value* property being set to the value entered by the user.

Be aware that if there is no value entered by the user, the placeholder text will appear in the spot of the input. If that is an issue, perhaps Javascript code could be added to hide inputs with no value, or else maybe a different solution is needed.

See it demonstrated in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/aelliott/pen/NjxzZV).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML`, you're retrieving the page's source HTML. However, input values don't get written to the source HTML. Instead, for any element, you need to call `document.getElementById(inputName).value` to retrieve whatever you put there.

If opening the new window isn't necessary, you can use window.print() on the current window and use `@media print {}` css to specify how you want it to appear. (You can use this syntax to create a noprint css class that will hide anything you don't want to appear.) This is likely the much easier solution depending on your use case.

Otherwise, I believe you'll have to manually extract each input value and concatenate it into your HTML.